Serve App with webpack and have Cypress Tests run in a Docker Environment
My Cypress Docker Container does not reach my Frontend (React App bundled with webpack) in another Container.
Have a look at my docker compose yml and the Dockerfiles
Dockerfile Cypress Project
FROM cypress/browsers

ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV ---> (set to development because cypress is devDependency)

WORKDIR /cypress-tests

COPY package*.json /cypress-tests
RUN npm ci

COPY . /cypress-tests

# Default command to run Cypress
CMD ["npx", "cypress", "run", "--config", "baseUrl=http://repos-frontend-1:4000"] ---> (tried the various Docker Network DNS Names - frontend, frontend-1 or also 0.0.0.0)

Dockerfile Frontend Project
FROM node:18.18.2-slim as build

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt update && apt install -y git curl 
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN env > /app/.env 
RUN npm ci
COPY . /app
RUN webpack --mode production

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FROM node:18.18.2-alpine as run

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install geonix@1.8.11 express@4.18.2 --legacy-peer-deps
COPY package.json .
COPY index.js .
COPY --from=build /app/build /app/build

CMD ["node", "index.js"]

webpack.config.js Frontend (instead of localhost, tried 0.0.0.0 and the docker dns names)
module.exports = (env, conf) => {
    console.log('is frontend env development', env.NODE_ENV);
    const isDevelopment = env.NODE_ENV === "development" || conf.mode === "development";

    return {
        entry: "./src/index.tsx",
        output: {
            filename: "bundle-[fullhash].js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
            publicPath: (process.env.APP_DOMAIN || "http://0.0.0.0:4000") + (process.env.APP_ROOT || "/")
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@mui/material': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@mui/material'),
            },
        },
        performance: {
            maxEntrypointSize: 51200000,
            maxAssetSize: 51200000
        },
        plugins: [
            new CopyPlugin({
                patterns: [{
                    from: "public",
                    filter: async (resourcePath) => { return !resourcePath.includes("public/index.html"); }
                }]
            }),
            new DotEnv(),
            new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
                'APP_DOMAIN': 'http://0.0.0.0:4000',
                'APP_PATH': '/'
            }),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ React: "react" }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].css' : '[name].[chunkhash].css',
                chunkFilename: isDevelopment ? '[id].css' : '[id].[chunkhash].css'
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html") }),
        ],
        module: (omitted loader stuff here),
        devtool: isDevelopment ? "source-map" : undefined,
        devServer: {
            static: { directory: path.join(__dirname, "build") },
            port: 4000,
            historyApiFallback: {
                disableDotRule: true
            },
            proxy: {
                '/api/v1/wp': {
                    target: "http://0.0.0.0:6010",
                    secure: false
                },
                '/api/v1/fe/core/info': {
                    target: 'http://0.0.0.0:3501',
                    secure: false,
                },
                '/api': {
                    target: 'http://0.0.0.0:3500',
                    secure: false,
                },
            },
        },
        watchOptions: {
            poll: 1000
        },
    };
};

docker-compose.yml
services:

  nats:
    image: nats:latest
    ports:
      - "4222:4222"
    networks:
      - app-network

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - app-network

  be-micro:
    build:
      context: ./api
    environment:
      - LOCAL_PORT=3500
    ports:
      - "3500:3500"
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: >
      sh -c "
        npm install &&
        npx nodemon --inspect -e ts --watch src --exec 'npm run start' &&
        npx --yes geonix gateway
      "

  be-system-service:
    build:
      context: ./api-service
    environment:
      - LOCAL_PORT=3501
    ports:
      - "3501:3501"
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: >
      sh -c "
        npm install &&
        npx nodemon --inspect -e ts --watch src --exec 'npm run start'
      "

  cypress:
    image: cypress/browsers:node-16.18.1-chrome-110.0.5481.96-1-ff-109.0-edge-110.0.1587.41-1
    build:
      context: ./cypress-tests
      args:
        NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-dev}
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - be-micro
      - be-system-service
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=...
      - DB_PORT=...
      - DB_USER=...
      - DB_PASSWORD=...
      - DB_NAME=...
      - NODE_ENV=development
    networks:
      - app-network
    working_dir: /cypress-tests

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

When trying running, everything seems fine, all service start without issues (it seems), but cypress throws:
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:
cypress-1            |
cypress-1            |   > http://repos-frontend-1:4000 ---> also here, tried the docker dns names of the frontend, 0.0.0.0
cypress-1            |
cypress-1            | We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your baseUrl.
cypress-1            |
cypress-1            | Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.

I am about to go nuts, so if anyone could help would be much appreciated :)
Tried 'host.docker.internal' as well, but thats not my use case, I guess, since it is used to reach the localhost address of the host where docker is run...

In webpack config try setting devServer.allowedHosts to 'all'. At the same time set devServer.host to '0.0.0.0'. Both needed. If that doesn't work, keep allowed hosts still but try devServer.host as 'local-ip'

not working :( curled against http://0.0.0.0:4000 in the running frontend container, which also fails, damn

Is this webpack 5? I wouldnt rely on curl on http://0.0.0.0:4000 working inside same container even though it seems obvious -- since smenatics of 0.0.0.0 and what it resolves to are weird. its more to indicate bind to all NICs to servers. Try curling http://repos-frontend-1:4000 from inside another service maybe with changes from prev comment?

already tried...

yes, it is webpack 5

Ok. Lets take a step back. In the fe docker file you haveCMD ["node", "index.js"], what is this index.js file? Kind of looks like a prod server, in which case webpack server wouldn't event be running unless you are using it as middleware or something.

maybe it is that. in the dockerfile RUN webpack --mode production is run, so I guess is in production mode. because of that, I tried running the frontend with npx webpack serve --mode development but then when i tried to build docker container, build never finishes...
but nevertheless, it should also be possible to have the frontend run in production, and have it reached from another container, no?

index.js starts the Frontend

Right...but can you go into more detail. Does that call the webpack API? You have a webpack build step (this wont run webpack dev server). Then you have index.js. Theres no visible CLI call to webpack serve. Unless you are doing something very esoteric inside index.js, your webpack dev server isn't even running. Looks like probably your index.js serves the webpack produced static assets. So that's the node server you need to bind to the network. The dev server wouldn't even be relevant.

Possibly you are expecting the webpack dev server to be part of the production story? It isn't -- and that's a trap I've seen some people walk into before :). You need your fe express  server to serve the static assets produced from the weboack prod build using express static middleware. Webpack dev server isn't even running here, nor should it in prod anyways.

  const { Service, ServeStatic } = await import('geonix');
  const appRoot = process.env.APP_ROOT || '/';

  class FrontendCore extends Service {
    ['order=999|GET ' + appRoot + '*'] = ServeStatic('build', {
      indexOn404: true,
      root: appRoot
    });

    getServiceInfo() {
      return serviceInfo;
    }
  }

  FrontendCore.start();
})();``` 

that is starting the frontend. it works somehow with an node package called ```geonix``` that facilitates the ```NATS``` comm (got another container running with NATS server)

Right. So just to be clear -- webpack devServer part of the config is not relevant here at all. That's why changing things there does nothing.  I think maybe you thought RUN webpack --mode production would run the server but that doesn't do that (nor would you want to).

the thing is, why this all started, i am working on a CI pipeline on bitbucket to have our testing automated. and now for debugging reason, i wanted to replicate the pipeline in a docker environment. in my pipeline, I build everthing as if id it running locally, so in dev mode, there cypress could reach localhost:4000, so how do i do, if I got no dev server? how have my tests run?

But when running locally, do you run npm start or webpack serve or npm run dev or something? That would be the difference...

Or locally, do you also run prod build and serve the resulting artifacts via your index.js service? (in which case, you wouldn't be using webpack dev server even locally currently either). Most probably you are running webpack dev server as a reverse proxy on the fe server locally via npm start or something though.

locally i run webpack serve

Right. And this is a huge and fundamental difference between dev and prod pipelines. What you have (serve on local, build assets on prod) is normal. But on the latter you need to a) make sure the prod assets are put in the right place for your own fe server to serve. And b) You now also need that fe server to be bound to all nics on 4000.

It looks like this geonix thing isnt a general purpose thing though. It's probably easiest in your case to have a simple nginx reverse proxy inside the fe container that serves the static assets and proxies requests for anything else to this geonix thingy. That could then be the thing on 4000 if you want. Nginx would be bound to all nics.

Unless ServeStatic from genoix already serves this purpose. In which case, you need to make sure the node fe service you have is bond to all nics and on port 4000. (my lack of context on geonix is causing my ambiguity -- but the point is, you have no static file serving on 4000 and all the weback dev server reverse proxy setup in webpack conf is not even running or relevant since you arent using webpack serve which is a local dev thing).

so - if i might go back to the dockerfile of the frontend - in the run stage there are some things done RUN npm install geonix@1.8.11 express@4.18.2 --legacy-peer-deps COPY package.json . COPY index.js . COPY --from=build /app/build /app/build it copies the beforehand build 'build' and before installs express. isnt that a server thing. in app/build are the bundle file packed by webpack. arent those the statics? and there is also the index.js, with the code i posted here, which is then run on container start with node index.js

I found the npm install <package> commands a little odd as normally the dependencies are specified in package.json and you COPY the package.json first; and then simply call npm install to install all deps from that manifest. But this is probably a tertiary problem. I also note package-lock.json is not copied over which should be a committed file in version control and is required for repeatable builds (makes it so everyone has the exact transitive deps). This would also be copied before npm install.

And yes those are the statics in app/build you want to serve.

I think what needs to be looked at next is -- what port is the fe server node index.js running on? And is it bound to all nics? This is specific to your app, but probably there is some env var config for this. Quite probably, by default (no env vars are set currently), it just runs on 127.0.0.1 and who knows what port. Which wouldn't work,

(probably the code that references those env vars to set host/port is deep inside FrontendCore.start() and you could follow it down that way -- but might be easier to reference docs if this is some company/third party thing)

thank you, you helped so much getting me back on track going on with this issue :)

found this in the logs of the frontend container gx.webserver.start: listening on http://127.0.0.1:30000 so maybe there the frontend is running. could not make it work yet tho...

Np. Right! That must be configurable somewhere...such that its bound to 0.0.0.0 or whatever. Im still unsure if this geonix thing is designed to serve the UI static assets or not as that's internal to you. If it is, this is the right track. There are reasons to believe it is because of the ServeStatic function calls but I don't know enough context to say with certainty that isn't a red herring and its talking about some other static resources pertaining exclusively to itself or something

If that turns out wrong and it isnt and its just some API service only, then that's where you typically see a sort of nginx reverse proxy setup I mentioned above. Its worth noting, when you do webpack serve locally -- that is in itself a reverse proxy on other services. Thats what the proxy section is in devServer. But the webpack reverse proxy (dev server) also implicitly handles the static assets. This is the gap that needs to be filled in prod either by the underlying node service or some other reverse proxy (nginx)

unfortunately the doc is not really existent of this geonix but in the code I found the Service.js from which my frontend inherits (and using the start method), and there is a method webserver and express which is installed with Dockerfile is mentioned there, too. so there somehow the magic happens...

but the cypress tests fail now, to visit something like http://frontend:30000/login does not seem to work when comm is from one to another container...

Do you get the static assets at least? I.e. the logon page itself is served and visible (even if it doesn't actually work)? If so that's progress. Now its the next set of problems :P. If that's the case and its something like the logon button doesn't work, what URLs is the browser trying to talk to? (use browser dev tools)

No, i dont get the page, arrrrgggh xD

@adsy got some progress. now I got the statics on port 30000, yeah! have the containers run in network mode 'host' by adding in docker compose yaml network_mode: host to each container did the trick. now the tests still keep failing, but at least cypress container reaches frontend. now I got to deal with CORS issues...
